# Virtual machine screen capture from the host

Tags: c#, api, vmware, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running a virtual machine (windows) from my host machine (windows vista).

I am looking for a way to build an application capable of make a screen capture of the virtual machine and return the active window title, but running in the host machine.

Vmware or Virtualbox is indifferent.
.Net preferably.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what have you tried?

Comment: I have read some web pages about screen capture but I haven't found anything about active window title. Very lost to try something yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows doesn't have a built-in cmd line method for getting screen captures, so you would have to have a 3rd party program installed on the virtual machine to take the screen capture.  Some good ones may be [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), [Screenshot-cmd](http://code.google.com/p/screenshot-cmd/), [SnapIt](http://github.com/90kts/snapIt), or [DuckLink](http://www.ducklink.com/p/command-line-screen-capture/).

Using VMware's vmrun utility, you can use [RunProgramInGuest](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/How_to_Remotely_Run,_List_and_Kill_Programs_Running_in_a_VMware_Virtual_Machine#Running_a_Program_in_a_VMware_Guest_System) to run a c# program on the VM that will use whatever program you choose to take the screen capture and then send it back to your host machine.  If I knew c# then I could give you a starting point, but unfortunately I've never written in it before.